# sql where clause in select statement issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, select

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have a database table called "Book", which has many columns and three columns are important in this question, they are

- Author, varchar;
- Country, varchar;
- Domain, varchar.

I want to write a store procedure with the following logics, but I do not know how to write (because of complex query conditions), appreciate if anyone could write a sample for me?

Input parameter: p_author as varchar, p_country as varchar, and p_domain as varchar

Query conditions:

1. if p_author is specified from input, then any row whose Author column LIKE %p_author% is satisfied with condition, if p_author is not specified from input every row is satisfied with this condition;
2. if p_country is specified from input, then any row whose Country column = p_country is satisfied with condition, if p_country is not specified from input every row is satisfied with this condition;
3. if p_domain is specified from input, then any row whose Domain column LIKE %p_domain% is satisfied, if p_domain is not specified from input every row is satisfied with this condition;

The results I want to return (must met with all following conditions):

- records met with either condition 1 or 2;
- records must meet with condition 3;
- return distinct rows.

For example, records which met with condition 1 and condition 3 are ok to return, and records which met with condition 2 and condition 3 are ok to return.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Is Query condition 3 correctly phrased? From the bullet points, it looks as though Query condition 3 should be "any row whose Domain column LIKE %p_domain% is satisfied" - ie. p_domain must be supplied, based on the second bullet point.

Comment: The original description is correct. But not very clear, sorry. :-)

It could be described in this way, if p_domain is null from input, then p_domain is always satisfied with condition 3 since if p_domain is not specified from input every row in the table is satisfied with this (means the 3rd) condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following should work:

```
 SELECT * 
FROM Books
WHERE (
   ((Author LIKE '%' + @p_author + '%' OR @p_author = '') OR 
   (Country LIKE '%' + @p_country + '%' OR @p_country = ''))
   AND (@p_author <> '' OR @p_country <> '')
) AND 
(Domain LIKE '%' + @p_domain + '%' OR '%' @p_domain = '')
```

Comment: Could I add another AND statement to the where clause in the future if there is one more must to have condition for the row to be returned as satisfied? I am not sure how many AND/OR can be added to where clause.

Comment: You should be able to add additional AND statements, just make sure you keep everything nested together logically.  You don't want to go overboard, but it should be doable.

Comment: you can add as many ANDs to this as you want, it won't really matter, you'll never use an index and you will be touching every row in the table regardless

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically changing searches based on the given parameters is a complicated subject and doing it one way over another, even with only a very slight difference, can have massive performance implications.  The key is to use an index, ignore compact code, ignore worrying about repeating code, you must make a good query execution plan (use an index).

Read this and consider all the methods.  Your best method will depend on your parameters, your data, your schema, and your actual usage:

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

If you have the proper SQL Server 2008 version (SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and later), you can use this little trick to actually use an index:

There isn't much you can do since you are using `LIKE`, but if you were using equality, you could add OPTION (RECOMPILE) onto your query, see Erland's article, and SQL Server will resolve the OR from within `(Column = @Param+'%'  OR @Param='') AND ...` before the query plan is created based on the run-time values of the local variables, and an index can be used if you weren't using `LIKE`.